# How to make a public image display in-text when pasted in Skype or other Social Medias

Tags: php, css, skype

I am a frequent user of Skype, and I have realised that when you paste a link into Skype **im using the desktop app for this** like example YouTube, the thumbnail is displayed in the chat.

So I was wondering if there is a specific type of class or area I need to make in my code, be `CSS` or `PHP` so that the Skype Spiders (if exist) pick up the image, and display it in the chat. - Being this is a commercially allowed thing to add to your site.

I have looked at the `Skype Developers` area on the site and on the Microsoft site, and there was no information regarding on my topic.

Comment: You mean drag'n'drop image to real Skype app and get that image via PHP or CSS?

Comment: @Justinas I mean as in when you link a video - Like example a YouTube video, there is a preview image for that link. It shows a small graphic for the link that is displayed. I develop my own site and wanted to set an image for the site.

Comment: @Jek Did you have a look at my answer? `:)`

Comment: @PraveenKumar I did and I've added all the code, just seeing if it works, does it take some time for it to happen?

Comment: @Jek Yes, it does. Skype servers would have cached your request so... :(

Comment: @Jek You can actually use a different URL to test this out.

Comment: Sure thing, I appreciate the answer and sorry for the delay :) @PraveenKumar

Comment: @Jek Thanks... Lemme know if you find something else as well. Happy to update the answer or have a chat in this sense.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Skype, Facebook, and others are using Open Graph Protocol to get those. You can find more information about [Open Graph Protocol](http://ogp.me/) online and a small code to achieve it is:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="/image.jpg"/>
<meta property="og:image:secure_url" content="https://mywebsite.com/image.jpg" />
```

These two should be present in your `<head />` tag. Also make sure you add the XML NameSpace to the `<html>` tag:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:og="http://ogp.me/ns#"
      xmlns:fb="https://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
```

You can also use multiple images, you just need to add multiple image meta tags in the order you want them to appear in. The user will then be presented with an image selector dialog in Facebook.